# Issue echoing the site's title in Genesis child theme

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I'm having an issue adding a dynamic site name/title to the footer with my Genesis theme. From their shortcode reference I've gathered that I should, I think, be able to add it in the below code in place of the Editable Link. Here's what I mean:

```
//* Change the footer text
add_filter('genesis_footer_creds_text', 'sp_footer_creds_filter');
function sp_footer_creds_filter( $creds ) {
    $creds = '[footer_copyright] <a href="/">Editable Link</a>';
    return $creds;
}
```

However, when I replace the Editable Link text with something like `$creds = '[footer_copyright] <?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>';` I get:

```
Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 291 of file wp-content/themes/genesis-sample-develop/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING)
```

I've tried several variations of `<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>` but nothing seems to want to work. What am I missing?

Comment: That indeed contains a syntax error. You should use concatenation like so: `'[footer_copyright] ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' );`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it! Cheers

Comment: I've done that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code indeed contains a syntax error, which is unescaped quotes:

```
$creds = '[footer_copyright] <?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>';   // bad - ' not escaped
$creds = '[footer_copyright] <?php echo get_bloginfo( \'name\' ); ?>'; // good - ' escaped
```

But even if you escape the quotes, the code will not work as expected.

So to make it work as expected, use concatenation like so:

```
$creds = '[footer_copyright] ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' );
```